# GMSMapView does not occupy full bounds

Tags: ios, google-maps, autolayout

I've designed the following layout on XCode:

[image]

The button Layout (Cancel, Sign Up) is pinned to the bottom layout guide. On top of that are 3 equally sized `UIView`s, each with 1px vertical spacing in between them.

The remaining space is occupied by `mapView`, which is a `UIView`. It is pinned to the top, leading and trailing layout guide. It also has 8px spacing between the building number view.

When I run the application on my iPhone 6, I get this:

[image]

The map is not drawn in all available space. I don't know why:

When setting up the map, I do pass the bounds of the mapView:

```
class RegisterAddressViewController: BaseViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mapView : UIView!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.setupMapView()
        self.setupLocationManager()
    }

    func setupMapView(){
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
                                                          longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
        self.gmsMapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.mapView.bounds, camera: camera)
        self.gmsMapView!.delegate = self
        self.mapView.addSubview(self.gmsMapView!)
    }

    //...
}
```

I do not believe it's an AutoLayout issue since no warning appears in the console and the light grey background of the mapView indicates that the layout is set correctly.

Is there some configuration that I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that *Auto Layout* hasn't run and sized your views at the time of `viewWillAppear`.  Move your code into an override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and it should work correctly.  Be careful though, because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can run multiple times, so check for that and only do your setup once or make sure it is OK to run `setupMapView` multiple times.

Comment: Judging by the name, I thought `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was already done by the time `viewWillAppear` gets called. My bad, I should have read in to the documentation to be sure. Thanks mate!